# How to fix sockettimeout and webdriver exception in selenium, while working in maven?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, maven-3, testng-eclipse

I'm executing a simple program in maven, open browser and enter url, after entering it has to print message. But every time when i run it as maven test it will show the below error but when i run the same test in testNG it won't show any error. need help to resolve this error

I tried extending the "wait time" while connecting and tried "retry on connection failure" (both are in okHttpClient class) also but no use.

```
    private WebDriver driver;
    String url = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/guru99home/";
    @Test
    public void testEasy() {

        driver.get(url);
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        okHttpClient.retryOnConnectionFailure();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "chrome driver path");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        System.out.println("Successfull");

    }

}


This is the error message i got
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 18.204 s <<< FAILURE! - in example.NewTest
[ERROR] testEasy(example.NewTest)  Time elapsed: 10.07 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
Build info: version: '3.9.0', revision: '698b3178f0', time: '2018-02-05T14:26:55.441Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-N356APG', ip: '192.168.1.4', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at example.NewTest.testEasy(NewTest.java:24)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at example.NewTest.testEasy(NewTest.java:24)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at example.NewTest.testEasy(NewTest.java:24)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   NewTest.testEasy:24 » WebDriver java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
Build...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\*****\*****\eclipse-new project\WebDriverTest\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.241 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-04T13:20:17+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: on which line you get the SocketTimeout? is it in driver.get(url)?

Comment: @Adi Ohana sometimes after opening the webpage socket time out will come and sometimes before browser gets open only, error will be thrown.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue on my end. One more thing, you are setting some values for OKHttpClient but it is not in use anywhere in your code. try to start a fresh project only with your specific test and see if issue still happens

Comment: @Adi Ohana i created the new maven project as you said and run the test but still the same issue is there.